# converting into swift 2.0 got error in managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

```
 func read()
 {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Coupons")

    var error: NSError?

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "coupon_id", ascending: true)

    // Set the list of sort descriptors in the fetch request,
    // so it includes the sort descriptor

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    for var i = 0; i < fetch_coupon_category.count ; i++ {

    //condition like here.
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "coupon_categories == %@", fetch_coupon_category[i])

 // Set the predicate on the fetch request
// Combine the two predicates above in to one compound predicate
//let the predicate on the fetch request

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate1
```

I'm trying to make this code into swift2 making some try catch functionality

```
        do{
            let fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
                as? [NSManagedObject]?

                if let results = fetchedResults {

                for (var i=0; i < results.count; i++) {

                    let single_result = results[i]

                    let out = single_result.valueForKey("coupon_name") as! String
                    tickets.append(single_result)

                }

            }
            else
            {
                print("cannot read")
            }
        }catch let fetchError as NSError{

            print("fetching error: \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
           // return nil

        }

    }

}
```

I'm getting error in manage

> 'try managedObjectContext' use unresolved identifier

how can I convert my code into swift 2.0 getting more error converting my code -.-

Comment: this code is my swift 1.2 its all working perfectly when converting into swift2 shit happens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try managedContext` instead of `try managedObjectContext` because actually you assigned value of `managedObjectContext` into `managedContext` in current viewcontroller